# Which language did emperors, empresses and other "official people" speak in the Yuan Empire?

Tags: social-history, language

Please, I need real information, not from films, k-dramas and etc. I mean the language of the "official people" like the emperor, empress and etc.

Comment: You mean as the official language? Given the size of the empire, I'd imagine that the people within it spoke a range of languages/dialects (just as they do today).

Comment: Welcome to History.SE . Can you tell us where you have already looked for information, and what you already found ?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: What is wrong with the information in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_dynasty#Society)?

Comment: @MCW I I have not overlooked something, the WP article mentions only that Yuan emperors *were able to* speak Chinese and that Khubilai was also *able to* speak Mongolian. I says nothing about whether later emperors could speak Mongolian, or about the relative roles of Chinese and Mongolian inside the Yuan court or among the ruling elite.

Comment: @Jan - your observations are not in the question.  All questions should document prior research and explain why Wikipedia, Google and other standard sources don't answer the question.  If only some emperors mastered Chinese, that is a strong indication that the official language was probably Mongolian.

Comment: So we have a new user, a non-trivial question and all that is missing is some boiler plate "I looked at wikipedia but the information there is too unspecific".

Comment: @Jan - I agree. Its frustrating because this *could* IMHO be a good question. I'd kinda like to take a crack at answering it. The problem is that it isn't really just "boilerplate". If it were, we could just add it ourselves and go on with answering the question. It serves the purpose of protecting users from spending large amounts of time researching something the poster didn't actually want, or had already looked at, and at present we don't have enough info from the OQ to add it ourselves (I tried).